# buffer function with matrix

Tags: matlab, buffer

I have a N by 7 matrix corresponding to a 7 channel input.
I would like to buffer this input in windows of 30 samples with 29 samples overlap.

for a 1 channel input I would use the function buffer

```
timeinterval = 30;
timeoverlap = 29;    
buf=buffer(input_vec,timeinterval,timeoverlap,'nodelay');
```

Is it possible to use the buffer function with the N by 7 matrix? I couldn't find how in the help.

Thanks

Comment: You aim for a 3D matrix result, with buffer index on third dimension?

Comment: yes, it would be nice

Comment: I am open also to other solutions, with high preference to the one that doesn't create heavy output...since I m working with very long input to analyze sequentially I have some memory constraints..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result is required to be a 3D array, signals indexed last, then:

```
%// Usually the test cases are given :-)
signals     = repmat(transpose(1:100), 1,7);
buff_length = 5;

%// No one-liners today
n_signals = size(signals, 2);
buff_cell = cell(1, n_signals);
for k = 1:n_signals
        buff_cell{k} = buffer(signals(:,k), buff_length);
end;

result = cat(3, buff_cell{:});
```